# AlertDialog doesn't show up

Tags: java, android

```
public void MsgBox(String title, String msg){

    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    dlgAlert.setMessage("The message");
    dlgAlert.setTitle("Titel");

    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);

    dlgAlert.create().show();
}
```

This is the method I am using, I don't understand what is wrong with it.  I've even replaced `null` with the common code you would add, but the box still won't pop up.  Any suggestions?

Comment: stupid question: are you sure you are calling `MsgBox`?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext());
```

maybe you're not calling it from a class that's actually an Activity

Answer (score 0):

Pass the context

Issue was that you are not creating AlertDialog object and you are showing alert dialog using AlertBuilder object.

**Update**

```
public void MsgBox(String title, String msg, Context context){
        AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dlgAlert.setMessage("The message");
        dlgAlert.setTitle("Titel");
        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);

            AlertDialog alertDialog = dlgAlert.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: I did what Sadiq told me to but now I get the following error:

Comment: @Lenfinalt I updated the code. Main error was you are not creating the AlertDialog object like AlertDialog alertDialog = dlgAlert.create(); and without creating object you are showing alert dialog using AlertDialogBuild object. This Upfated code surly solve your problem